# How to set nullable constraint on uploaded file field in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, validation, constraints

I have a form that has fields `name` and `image` where I want to upload image file. The `name` field is required but the `image` field is optional. But I'm  having trouble finding the right Assert constraint for the `image` property to make it nullable. Every time I tried submit it complains about empty file.

I've tried `NULL`, `NotBlank`, `Blank`, they all doesn't work.

```php
class Post {

    public $name;

    /**
    * Assert\Image(maxSize="2048k")
    *
    */
    public $image;

}
```

Comment: can you show some code where you set the properties and code where you validate the object? because the Image constraint should allow null values according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html (Basic Usage at the end. Image extends File, so this should be true for Image as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($document)
          ->add('name')
          ->add('file', 'file', array('required'=>false)
          ->getForm()
      ;
```

You may also need to specify on your entity that the field can be null

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string", nullable="true")
     */
     protected $file;
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the `'required' => false` in the form builder works